# Whats the issue I'm facing here with my convert to rigify?

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image: Ive been receiving an issue with Blender 2.93 with the diffeomorphic addon, after importing the model to Blender, I seem to have this issue where the program cannot find the lower abdomen]

Ive been receiving an issue with Blender 2.93 with the diffeomorphic addon, after importing the model to Blender, I seem to have this issue where the program cannot find the lower abdomen

Comment: you're rigify addon is not compatible with your current blender version. check the Rigify documentation to see which blender version you need

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie -- imagine if there were some (pop-up) summary that suggested this?!  software too complicated, she said.